# Set object x position to object y position MINUS another value (JavaScript / CSS)

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way I set the top margin of x to the same as y, but alter it slightly?

Something like this:

`x.style.marginTop = y.style.marginTop + "-1vh";`

Comment: you can use `calc` CSS method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. But you need to make sure you are adding the values in the correct context.

For eg. if I have a div with top-margin set to '2vh'

```
<div id="y" style="margin-top:2vh"></div>
```

Now getting margin-top style using JS would look something like this -

```
let reqMargin = document.getElementById('y').style.marginTop;
console.log(reqMargin) // '2vh';
```

You get the point? Now that you get the value of the margin-top, you can extract the numeric value from it and use it wherever you need. In your case it will be something like this -

```
let absMargin = reqMargin.match(/\d+/g); //get the numeric value from the string value
x.style.marginTop = (absMargin - 1) + "vh";
```

That will get your work done.

Comment: Thank you, this helped -- my css for y marginTop used calc() and your advice about getting the numeric value led me to experiment by doing this:

```y.substring(0, y.length - 1) + " + " + -6 + 'px)';```

Which worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The style object on an element will always take and return strings for its attributes.

So what you're looking for might be something like

```
x.style.marginTop = `calc(${y.style.marginTop} - 1vh)`;
```

The string will always be represantative to what you would write in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That look like:

```
let variable = y.style.marginTop + 5;
x.style.marginTop = variable + 'px'
```

But:

1. Style property wanted a string value like '120px' or 'auto'
   If you write only `y.style.marginTop = 120` that would be wrong
2. Remember about type conversion
   Result of `y.style.marginTop + "-1vh"` is string value like "100px-1vh"

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, you can use the 'calc' function to calculate values.

```
x {
  height: calc(100px  + -1vh);
}
y {
  height: 100px;
}
```